# Clustering Glassfish Web Sessions with Terracotta

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, terracotta

Can Terracotta 3.5.x be configured to cluster web sessions in Glassfish 3.1?

I would like to secure a clustered Jersey application using a JDBC Realm. Multicasting for native Clustering is not available in the production environment.

If it is possible, can anyone help with the configuration steps or a guide please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can Terracotta 3.5.x be configured to cluster web sessions in Glassfish 3.1?

I don't think so. The [Platform Support for Terracotta 3.5](http://www.terracotta.org/confluence/display/release/3.5.0+Platform+Support) page indicates Glassfish V3 support:

> for Ehcache, Quartz, **but not Web Sessions**.

The [documentation for installing web-sessions using Terracotta 3.5.2](http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/web-sessions-install.html#443822792_pgfId-1010080) would also support this conclusion, since Glassfish is not mentioned.

However, you can confirm latest availability by contacting *info@terracotta.org*

Comment: Well timed! I was literally typing up a similar answer after contacting Terracotta! The only additional information I've gleaned is that an alternative to clustering a JDBC Realm in the Glassfish container is to use the Terracotta Spring Security integration TIM (tim-spring-security-2.0) as you can still cluster Java applications deployed on Glassfish.